# Display Notification In Flutter When App is Closed

Tags: flutter, dart

I Have try to display notification in flutter app I already used [FlutterLocalNotificationPlugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

1. When app is open the notification is display but
2. When flutter app is Closed but it is not working or notification is not display ,I`am new in flutter please help me

//This is Function Initialization

```
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin localNotificationsPlugin;
  Future showNotification() async {
  var androidDetails = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
  "channelId",
  "channelName",
  "channelDescription",
  importance: Importance.max,
  priority: Priority.high,
  playSound: true,
  largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('tele_marketing'),
);
 var iosDetails = new IOSNotificationDetails(
    //sound: 'bells.mp3',
    presentAlert: true,
    presentBadge: true,
    presentSound: true);
    var generalNotification =
    new NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iosDetails);
    await localNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0, "Total Leads", totalLeads.toString(), generalNotification);
  }
```

// This is function Call

```
 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 //Build Notification in IOS and Android
 var androidNotification =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('tele_marketing');
 var iosNotification = new IOSInitializationSettings(
  requestAlertPermission: true,
  requestBadgePermission: true,
  requestSoundPermission: true,
 );
 var notification = new InitializationSettings(
     android: androidNotification, iOS: iosNotification);
 localNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
 localNotificationsPlugin.initialize(notification);
}
```

//When API is call display the function app is open or closed

```
                 if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    if (totalLeads > totLeads) {
                      playSound();
                      showNotification();
                      totLeads = totalLeads;
                    } else {}
```

Comment: Please post your code and what you did to test it.

Comment: @nvoigt Code is updated please check it